# Estilos ComboBox Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo problemas con un *comboBox*, generado con *ruby*. No logro ver por qué motivo no está tomando los estilos de *Bootstrap* el *comboBox* **Marca**.

El formulario es *_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_with(model: cotizacion, scope: :cotizacion, local:true, class: "form-inline") do |form| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.select :marca, 
          options_for_select([["SUBARU", "T"], ["KIA", "S"]], 
          class: "combobox form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="combobox form-control" name="inline">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select a State</option>
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
      <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    </select>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

La diferencia de estilos se ve reflejada en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Estilos Bootstrap]

La idea es obtener el mismo estilo del *comboBox* `Select State` y hasta el momento obtengo el estilo de comboBox `Subaru`.

Desde ya muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que no estás asignando el estilo correctamente; i.e. lo estás asignando en las opciones, no en el `select`.

Esto se debe a que el *helper* `select` está definido<sup>1</sup> de una forma diferente a los demás *helpers*:

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

Como podrás ver, el método acepta dos *hashes*, uno para opciones adicionales (`options = {}`) y otro para las opciones de html (`html_options = {}`); en este último es donde debes pasar el atributo `class`.

Dado que no estás pasando ninguna opción adicional, debes pasar ese *hash* vacío, para después pasar el *hash* con las opciones de html; por ejemplo:

```
<%= form.select :marca,
      options_for_select([["SUBARU", "T"], ["KIA", "S"]]), 
      {},
      { class: "combobox form-control" } %>
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Puedes ver la documentación del método (en inglés) en [este enlace](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select).*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

No enviaste el formulario entero, pero veo un par de errores que pueden estar causando el problema. Primero tienes estos 4 div:

```
                     <div class="container">
                     <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-2">
                     <div class="form-inline">
                     <div class="form-group">
```

de los cuales solo estás cerrando 3:

```
                 </div> 
                 </div> 
             </div>
```

luego tienes un `form_with` que te genera un tag `<form>` y dentro de éste mas adelante pusiste un `<form class="form-inline">`, lo cual no es correcto ya que los form no [deben ir anidados](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379622/895789).
Creo que una aproximación mas cercana a lo que buscas, obviamente excluyendo el botón de "recibir ofertas" y otros elementos que dejaste fuera del código que muestras, sería algo como esto:

```
<%= form_with(model: cotizacion, scope: :cotizacion, local:true, class: "form-inline") do |form| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.select :marca, options_for_select([["SUBARU", "t"], ["KIA", "s"]], class: 'combobox form-control') %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="combobox form-control" name="inline">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select a State</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    </select>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

PD: La palabra es "estilo", no "stylo".

Comment: Hola @Alter, aplique lo comentado, el comportamiento es el mismo. He modificado el formulario para que solo muestre los elementos comentados. Alguna otra idea?  Muchas GRACIAS!!